# How do i join 3 different types of sql queries into 1

Tags: mysql, join

I have one main query and based on it's results i have to create 3 more in order to display all the data i need. This loop, however, creates too many queries to the server. I understand it's possible to avoid that with SQL joins, but i'm not how will that work in my case.

```
SELECT * FROM `newLoads` WHERE `id` like '%".$term."%' OR `loadNumber` like '%".$term."%' ORDER BY `puDate` DESC 
//this is my main query and for every result it produces i query the following in **while** loop:


SELECT count(*) FROM `newStops` where idLoad = '".$load['id']."'

SELECT newStops.idConsignee, consignees.name, consignees.address FROM `newStops` INNER JOIN `consignees` ON newStops.idConsignee = consignees.id WHERE idLoad = '".$load['id']."' ORDER by stopNumber ASC LIMIT 1

//the last one is the same as the previous but it's ordered by stopNumber DESC
SELECT newStops.idConsignee, consignees.name, consignees.address FROM `newStops` INNER JOIN `consignees` ON newStops.idConsignee = consignees.id WHERE idLoad = '".$load['id']."' ORDER by stopNumber DESC LIMIT 1
```

Right now i'm combining all results in a JSON output and i need to keep it the same way

Answer (score 0):

This query is not debugged enough:

```
SELECT 
  t1.*, 
  COUNT(t2.*) as newStops_count,
  t3.name, t3.address,
  MAX(t3.stopNumber),
  MIN(t3.stopNumber)
FROM `newLoads` t1
LEFT JOIN `newStops` t2
ON t2.idLoad = t1.id
INNER JOIN `consignees` t3
ON t2.idConsignee = t3.id 

WHERE `id` like '%".$term."%' 
  OR `loadNumber` like '%".$term."%' 
ORDER BY `puDate` DESC
```

so if you can provide sqlfiddle with some data that would help a lot.